# Microsoft Graph API how to send an attachment in a chat

Tags: python, python-requests, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use the Microsoft Graph API to send messages with attachments to chats or channels.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-send-a-message-with-file-attachment-in-it

I can send normal messages already just fine like this:

```
def post_message(chat_id: str, subject: str = "", content_type: str = "text", content: str = "") -> None:
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chat_id}/messages"

    json = {
        "subject": subject,
        "body": {
            "contentType": content_type,
            "content": content
        }
    }

    res = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=json)
```

I try to copy the body from the example in the link above, substitute for my values and swap json variable for this one:

```
attachment_id = '7QW90B10D7-B5AK-420A-AC78-1156324A54F2' # not real, only to show how it looks like
json = {
    "body": {
        "contentType": 'html',
        "content": f'i dunno what i\'m doing. <attachment id="{attachment_id}"></attachment>'
    },
    'attachments': [
        {
            'id': attachment_id,
            'contentType': 'reference',
            'contentUrl': 'https://foo.sharepoint.com/sites/bar/User%20documentation/Databricks/Databricks%20guide.pptx',
            'name': 'Databricks guide.pptx'
        }
    ]
}
```

I get `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url`

What's wrong with the code? How to get attachment id from a file correctly because I am not sure I got the right value?

Comment: maybe you need to add "\" around the attachment_id as well like in the example: `<attachment id=\"153fa47d-18c9-4179-be08-9879815a9f90\">`

Comment: Doesn't work either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with your code, (using both formats `<attachment id=\"\">` and `<attachment id="">`), so it seems the error is probably with your `attachment_id`.

I retrieved the `driveItem ID` by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68434320/18748575), where the `driveItem ID` is the GUID value in the `eTag` property in the response.

> You could get the file by the path:
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{item-path}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drive/root:/%7Bitem-path%7D)
>
> For example:
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/test.docx](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drive/root:/test.docx)
>
> If the file is in a folder, it would be like this:
> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/folder1/test.docx](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/drive/root:/folder1/test.docx)

Sample request after obtaining the ID

```
access_token = ""

attachment_name = "file.txt"
attachment_path = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents"
attachment_id = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123"
attachment_url = f"{attachment_path}/{attachment_name}"

chat_id = ""

req_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{chat_id}/messages"

req_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

json = {
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": f"Test message <attachment id=\"{attachment_id}\"></attachment>"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": attachment_id,
            "contentType": "reference",
            "contentUrl": attachment_url,
            "name": attachment_name
        }
    ]
}

result = requests.post(url = req_url, headers = req_headers, json = json)
```

Comment: Hmm, I managed to do it using your code BUT I didn't change the attachment_id (still "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123"), what's happening? It works with random numbers too like 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111